# ::AddFontMemResourceEx' has not been declared

Tags: c++, winapi

I am following this tutorial  [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42041/How-to-Use-a-Font-Without-Installing-it#addres) to load font from resource.
I have included the Wingdi.h header [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), yet I am getting "::AddFontMemResourceEx' has not been declared" error while compiling, same error for ::RemoveFontMemResourceEx as well

What could possibly be the cause ?

*OS: Windows 7, Compiler : MinGW*

Comment: Have you tried without the scope operator? E.g. just `AddFontMemResourceEx`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes I did, but same result.

Comment: It is a later addition to the winapi, available since Windows 2000.  You have to tell MinGW what [version of Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you target.

Comment: @HansPassant Now I am getting errors on other part of the code : COLORREF LWA_COLORKEY  = 0x00000001; "[Error] expected primary-expression before numeric constant" which was working fine till I added the winver

Comment: `LWA_COLORKEY` is already defined, in `winuser.h`

Comment: @JonathanPotter So it wasn't showing error earlier because it isn't defined in winuser.h version prior to Windows 2000 ?

Comment: Correct, because alpha blending functionality was only added in Win2k.

Answer (score 3):

`wingdi.h` will not declare `AddFontMemResourceEx()` if `_WIN32_WINNT` is not at least `0x0500` (aka `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN2K`).